# how to get current model name from url odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I need to get current model name from this url:

```
http://localhost:8069/web#view_type=form&model=system.audit&menu_id=221&action=229
```

Here the model name is system.audit.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) built-in library in python

Try this snippet:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = "http://localhost:8069/web#view_type=form&model=system.audit&menu_id=221&action=229"
uri = urlparse(url)
qs = uri.fragment
print parse_qs(qs).get('model', None)
# ['system.audit']
```

[image]

It is working fine for me, check if the model is in query params when you're getting in real-time

Comment: @Tessnim check out my edited answer. It is working fine for me.

Comment: kanban thanks it's totally working !!! 
But I was looking for something more general : I want to get the model from the current page I'm working on not only a static url. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score -1):

In python 3, try this:

```
from urllib import parse

result = parse.parse_qs("http://localhost:8069/web#view_type=form&model=system.audit&menu_id=221&action=229")['model'][0]
print(result)
```

For python 2 use `urlparse.urlparse.parse_qs()`.